# How to integrate active diretory into Grafana docker container?

Tags: docker, active-directory, grafana

i deployed docker container for Grafana, and i would like to integrate active directory into it, How can i do that ? and how can i know if it works ?

Any help would be really appriciated!

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/auth/ldap/

Comment: i have seen this web page before, but i do not know how to integrate it since i am suing docker container

Comment: What problems are you running in to because of the Docker container?

Comment: actually i used volumes to integrate the files .ini and .toml, but i do not know how to verify if it works.

Comment: and i do not know which lines (in both .ini and .toml files) should i change